# How to change the Android Studio text selection mode to default?

Tags: android-studio, editor, selection, mode, cursor-position

When I click on a blank area after ";", my cursor doesn't move to ";", but moves exactly where I clicked.
When I try to select multiple lines, it selects only the text in that area, rather than all the text in those lines.

I don't know how to get back to the default text selection mode. Thanks for the help.

[That's happen when I select a text zone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPuIa.png)

[That's happen when I click in after ";"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IwP5V.png)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems like you have enabled column selection mode. Try to disable it.
Shortcut> CTRL+Shift+Paste on Windows

or

[Menu disable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6iAeB.png)

Answer (score 0):

Another reason for the behavior is 'Always keep trailing spaces on caret line' checkbox disabled in Android Studio > Preferences > General. So make sure it's enabled